# npm install fails after update for windows 10

Tags: ember.js, npm

I, after update my windows, to windows 10, I cannot run `npm` commands.

I am trying to install `ember-cli` but I got many errors.

```
F:\DEV\Ember\Ember1>npm install -g ember-cli
SyntaxError: Error parsing C:\Users\vitorpfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\extend\package.json: Unexpected token p
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:81:52)
    at tryPackage (module.js:91:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:153:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:323:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vitorpfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js:17:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\vitorpfn\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\vitorpfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\extend\package.json

npm ERR! Error parsing C:\Users\vitorpfn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\extend\package.json: Unexpected token p
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I already uninstall node and install again but the problems still the same.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can find instructions for [installing ember-cli on Windows here](http://yoember.com/nodejs/the-best-way-to-install-node-js/) or [here](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#windows)

Most important steps:

1. Install Node.js from [the official installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/stable/)
2. Always open PowerShell or CMD as Administrator.
3. Install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)
4. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run `$ Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope Process`
5. Install Ember-CLI-Windows: `$ npm install -g ember-cli-windows`
6. Run Ember-CLI-Windows: `$ ember-cli-windows`
7. Log out and log back in your Windows
8. Update npm: `$ npm install -g npm`
9. Install ember-cli: `$ npm install -g ember-cli`

You have to use PowerShell for certain settings, but for long term, probably better if you use Git Shell.